# How to retrieve the default Zend_View object from a controller

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

If I do this

```
public function indexAction()
    {

        $view = new Zend_View();

        $registrationForm = new Form_NewAwatag();

        $view->assign((array) $registrationForm);

        echo $view->render("index.phtml");

    }
```

it will create a new Zend_View object. How can I use the default Zend_View object?

Is it correct how I pass object to the view script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the view by using $this->view;
Assign values with $this->view->variable = $value

Comment: I really thank you :) Are you an expert about using Zend Framework? Can I ask your Skype ID?

Comment: I'm not an expert, more of an enthusiastic amateur :0)

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be stripped down to this

```
public function indexAction()
{

    $registrationForm = new Form_NewAwatag();

    $this->view->assign('myForm', $registrationForm);

}
```

Because the Zend MVC construct will automatically render the `index.phtml` file while it is the `indexAction` beeing called. In the view your form can be accessed by `$this->myForm`.